# WPF apply margin on ImageBrush in Ellipse?

Tags: wpf, margin, ellipse, imagebrush

Please take a look at my following code:

```
<Grid>
    <Ellipse StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="White">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="someImage.png"/>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
    </Ellipse>
</Grid>
```

What I'm trying to do is to `margin` the `someImage.png` `5px` from left and `5px` from top. I'm wondering if it's possible as I couldn't find any `margin` property available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put two Ellipses on top of each other like so:

```
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="White"/>
        <Ellipse Margin="5" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="White">
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="someImage.png"/>
            </Ellipse.Fill>
        </Ellipse>
    </Grid>
```

The grid will put all the items in the same row/column on top of each other.

Comment: Yea that's 1 way of doing it ...
you have to use this above method
because there's no inbuilt property which is gonna help your case ..

Comment: @lain: I'm sorry but I just found out something weird. If I'm to just copy and paste your code, there will be 2 circle appear which can be explained because you are moving the whole inner ellipse with margin = 5

Comment: @lain: If I'm to remove the `StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="White"`, then I will see the `imagebrush` overlay on top of the `outer ellise`